# iPad is not connecting it's showing OS Version

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I am new for iOS and when I connect my iPad with my system it's showing an exception like in the image below.

I am using Xcode 6.1.1 and the iPad is running iOS 8.4.1.

[[image: Xcode screenshot[1]]

Comment: You should update your Xcode to support IOS8.4.1

Comment: which version of xcode suitable ?

Comment: you update your Xcode 6.4.

Comment: to the newest formal version

Answer (score 1):

If you're running iOS 8.4.1 on your iPad, then you'll need to upgrade to **[Xcode 6.4](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/)**

additional [reference](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7180040?start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 1):

When you running on device then above problem occur, so You have to download new Xcode, Download Xcode 6.4 as below links.

[XCode 6.4](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.4/Xcode_6.4.dmg)

Answer (score 0):

You will require Xcode 6.4 in-order to mount your iPad: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when you plug in a device that is running an OS version above what your current version of Xcode is.

One solution is to always use the most recent non-beta versions of Xcode and iOS.

However, if you have a beta version of iOS on your device, but still want to develop and build with the non-beta release of Xcode, there is a workaround!

1) Have both the current release of Xcode, and the Xcode-beta installed on your machine.

2) Make sure they are both closed.

3) Plug-in your device.

4) Open Xcode-beta and allow it to recognize your device (process symbols...)

5) With phone still plugged-in, quit Xcode-beta.

6) Open stable Xcode version, and your device will be recognized!

I currently do this all the time because I have iOS 9 beta on my test device, but submitting apps to TestFlight using Xcode 7 (beta) is not yet supported, so I needed to use Xcode 6.4 as my main IDE.